# WPF Opacity in a general style

Tags: wpf, triggers, styles, opacity

I have this `style` that works as expected. I'm trying to generalize it for all controls.

Issue: if I replace the type ComboBox with Control. It does not work anymore.
I'm trying to avoid creating a style for each type of control.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
<Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Path=myProperty}"/>
<Style.Triggers>
<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
<Setter Property="ComboBox.Opacity" Value="1" />
</Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a way to do exactly what you want.  While this won't allow you to avoid defining styles for each type it does cut down on the duplicated code by using BasedOn to inherit the style you define once:

```
<Resources>
    <Style x:Key="InvisibleWhenDisabled" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Path=myProperty}"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource InvisibleWhenDisabled}"/>
    <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource InvisibleWhenDisabled}"/>
</Resources>
```

Comment: it does not work. In the Opacity setter, ControlType.Opacity has be specified. Otherwise, the style will not change Opacity.

Comment: @John Something else must be going on.  In my simplest example (window a ComboBox and button which toggles combo.IsEnabled) it correctly changes the Opacity.  What value are you setting the Opacity value to?  In your original example you use Opacity="1" which means 100% opaque.